# cocoa indexOfObject returns unexpected value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In the code segment below, the following should search for a string in the array, and if found, replace that string at that index with "Hello World".  (I realize that there is probably a better way to do this, I need to understand how indexOfObject works though)

```
if([arrayOfNames containsObject:string]){
            NSUInteger indexFound = [arrayOfNames indexOfObject:string];
            int castedIndex = (int) indexFound;
            arrayOfNames[castedIndex] = @"Hello World!";
```

All works well, except that the "indexFound" returns the value of 9223372036854775807 instead of an expect 0-25 value.

Anybody have any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Look at the docs for `indexOfObject:` and references to `NSNotFound`.

Comment: FYI - do not cast an `NSUInteger` to `int`. That's a bad idea. Use the proper data types.

Comment: As @rmaddy has pointed out the value you are seeing is `NSNotFound`, however that is not your problem. As you first check using `containsObject:` *before* calling `indexOfObject:` the latter should not return `NSNotFound`. There is nothing obviously wrong with your code, and it executes correctly, so you problem is elsewhere or in summarising  your code for the question you have lost the error. For the code as shown the only obvious way the `containsObject:` would succeed and the `indexOfObject:` then fail would be concurrent mutation of `arrayOfNames`. HTH

Comment: @CRD Yeah, I didn't notice the use of `containsObject:` until after I posted my comment. I agree the posted code shouldn't give `NSNotFound`. However, the casting of the `NSUInteger` to `int` is a bad idea.